# undefined local variable 'image' for Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, io, shrine

I would like to encrypt a file before storing it on S3. I'm using Shrine for uploads, and Lockbox for encryption. `Shrine#upload` takes an IO-like object, but the [Lockbox documention](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox#shrine) excludes some steps that are needed for setting this up. It simply says to do something like:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
 validates_presence_of :image

 lockbox = Lockbox.new(key: ENV['LOCKBOX_MASTER_KEY'])
 PhotoUploader.upload(lockbox.encrypt_io(image), :store)
end
```

In this case, `image` is the undefined local variable.

If the file is user uploaded (and whitelisted in the controller), how would I access it in the model so that I can perform this operation when it is saved?

Answer (score 1):

You could move this into a `before_save` method.  You could also change it to `after_save` if you wanted to do it then (it was a little unclear from your question).

```
before_save :encyrpt_image

def encrypt_image
  lockbox = Lockbox.new(key: ENV['LOCKBOX_MASTER_KEY'])
  PhotoUploader.upload(lockbox.encrypt_io(self.image), :store)
end
```